# Concatenating input parameters as variables for use inside batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

command line parameters are either fed to and read by batch file or hard coded in batch file

```
Set Target_computer = %1
REM  Get Source URL
Set SOURCE_URL = %2
REM Set Source Directory
SET SOURCE_DIR = \reference_data_update
```

and display when bat file executes.  However, when two of them are concatenated

```
xcopy %SOURCE_URL%%SOURCE_DIR% d:\dqxi\11_7\reference_data /Y/H/S/R
```

they are not read.  The command echoes as

```
xcopy    d:\dqxi\11_7\reference_data /Y/H/S/R
```

How can I get these variables to work in the batch file to perform the work I need the bat file to perform (xcopy from the source server's reference_data_update directory to the target server's reference_data directory)?

Comment: Looks like you are not passing any parameters to your batch file.

Comment: parameters are passed from either the command line or enterprise scheduling software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try removing the spaces (near the set command)

```
@echo off
Set Target_computer=%1
REM  Get Source URL
Set SOURCE_URL=%2
REM Set Source Directory
SET SOURCE_DIR=\reference_data_update
::and display when bat file executes. However, when two of them are concatenated

echo %SOURCE_URL%%SOURCE_DIR% d:\dqxi\11_7\reference_data /Y/H/S/R
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spaces before and after your equals signs in you SET statements.